# Agent Mulder, Resharper 8.1, VS 2013 and StructureMap

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, visual-studio-2013, resharper-8.0, resharper-8.1

I have the above setup, and DI is working just well in code. Unfortunately Agent Mulder is not showing the visual cues. I installed it through Extension Manager. Is this all that I need to do?

Thanks,
D.

Comment: Hi! I'm the author of Agent Mulder, I'm sorry, but I haven't yet ported it to ReSharper 8.1. I'll work on that very soon!

Comment: That explains it perfectly, thank you :) I shall await with bated breath!

Comment: The wait is over :) I just pushed a 8.1-compatible version. Please update your extensions in the gallery! And thanks for using Mulder :) Please let me know if something doesn't work for you!

Comment: I'm glad I saw this question. I discovered this plugin and installed it, as I use Ninject quite a lot.

Comment: I am having the same issue - no visual cues at all. I have 2 projects, 1 using autofac, 1 using structuredmap - neither show any visual cues. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just pushed an updated version that supports ReSharper 8.1. Please update your extensions in the gallery.

Comment: Now THAT is fast service! Thank you very much, highly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't appear to be working. In R# Extension Manager it says 1.1.1, but under `Resharper > Options > Plugins` it says 1.1.0.0. There are still no expected visual cues showing.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry you're having problems. Just a quick question: did it work in versions previous to 8? If so, could you please open an [issue on github](https://github.com/hmemcpy/AgentMulder/issues) with a small sample of your registration code? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this is the first time I have installed Agent Mulder. I did not use it in previous major versions of R#.

Comment: Ah, I see. Still, I would really appreciate a sample of your code you use for the registration/scanning. Maybe it's an unsupported scenario (or a bug :(). Thanks!

Comment: I used the StructureMap.MVC4 Nuget package. Here's my scan and register code:
        `public static IContainer Initialize()
        {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.Scan(scan =>
                {
                    scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                });
                x.For<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore<IdentityUser>>()
                    .Use<UserStore<IdentityUser>>();
            });
            return ObjectFactory.Container;
        }`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll have a look at it ASAP!